# retrofit async не успевает загрузить данные

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, retrofit

Использую ассинхронные запросы. В принципе понятно, почему данные не успевают отображаться в `RecyclerView`.
У меня есть класс `ChesselistFragment`. Я в конструкторе вызываю метод `populateData`, и он начинает собирать данные. Я бы хотел и  `RecyclerView` инициализировать в этом методе, но эт ж фрагмент. Как я смогу получить `ViewGroup`?

В общем.

1. Или мне нужно сделать синхронный запрос, обернув retrofit в
   `AsyncTask` (что не есть комильфо имхо. С таким же успехом я мог все
   сделать и просто http запросами)
2. Или мне нужно как то получить
       `ViewGroup` фрагмента, до его `onCreateView`, что звучит абсурдно)
       Надеюсь гуру помогут советом

   ```
   private void populateData(int currentPage)
   {

           restClient = new RestClient();
           restClient.getNewsService().getNews(currentCategory,currentPage, new Callback<List<ApiResponse>>() {
           @Override
           public void success(List<ApiResponse> apiResponse, Response response) {

               for (int i=0; i<apiResponse.size(); i++){
                   Log.e("Axixa", String.valueOf(apiResponse.get(i).getId()));
                   News news = new News(
                           apiResponse.get(i).getId(),
                           apiResponse.get(i).getTitle(),
                           apiResponse.get(i).getPreviewImage(),
                           apiResponse.get(i).getDate());
                   hs.add(news);

               }
               if (lNews.size()>0) page++;
               lNews.clear();
               lNews.addAll(hs);

               init();
           }

           @Override
           public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

           }
       });

      }

      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cheese_list, container, false);

   mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycleralda);

   mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration( // Добавление разделителя
           getActivity()
   ));

   mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
   mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
   if (page==0){
       mRecyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(lNews, getActivity());
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerviewAdapter);

   }


         return rootView;
   }
   ```

public void init() {

```
    if (mRecyclerView==null || mRecyclerviewAdapter==null){
        mRecyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(lNews, getActivity());

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerviewAdapter);}
    else{

    }

    mRecyclerviewAdapter.loadNews(lNews);
    mRecyclerviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. В своей реализации адаптера `RecyclerView.Adapter` сделайте метод для добавления / замещения данных. В конце этого метода не забудьте вызвать один из методов `notify...()` родительского адаптера для уведомления RecyclerView о том, что данные изменились.
2. В `onCreateView()` создавайте экземпляр своего адаптера с пустыми данными, присвойте его переменной фрагмента, установите его вашему RecyclerView.
3. Загрузку данных лучше инициировать в `onStart()` или `onResume()`.
4. В callback'е вызовите метод добавления данных у адаптера.
5. Запросы к сети лучше вынести в `Service`. В текущем варианте вы не учитываете жизненный цикл фрагмента.

Comment: У меня есть уже метод  ```java
public void init() {

        if (mRecyclerView==null || mRecyclerviewAdapter==null){
            mRecyclerviewAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(lNews, getActivity());

            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mRecyclerviewAdapter);}
        else{

        }

        mRecyclerviewAdapter.loadNews(lNews);
        mRecyclerviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Comment: Вы вызываете `notifyDataSetChanged` до того, как данные реально появятся. См. отредактированный ответ, описал примерный скелет более подробно. Вообще если вам не критично использовать именно `RecyclerView`, то перейдите на `ListView` и со стандартным `ArrayAdapter` - меньше кода нужно будет писать. Логика работы с ним точно такая же.